# Phone Gap npm installation error

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, phonegap-build

After reading the getting started guide of phonegap as mentioned there i have installed nodejs and i am trying to install the ponegap by using `npm install -g phonegap` but i am facing a problem in completing out the process i have searched and google for any of the solution and some of the sites they suggested saying install the old version as if the new version had the bugs and i tried installing the old by `npm install -g phonegap@3.4` but nothing worked out, any help will be appreciated

this was the error i got when i use `npm install -g phonegap`

```
C:\Users\Admin>npm install -g phonegap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/prompt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect-phonegap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qrcode-terminal
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap-build
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pluralize
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Admin
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect-phonegap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/prompt
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qrcode-terminal
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap-build
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pluralize
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Install Git first. try this link http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

And then include the Git bin folder path in your 'Path' variable in Environment variables.(C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :

1. Download and install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/). Following installation, you should be able to invoke node and npm on your command line.
2. Download and install a [git client](http://git-scm.com/), if you don't already have one. Following installation, you should be able to invoke git on your command line.
3. Install the cordova module using npm utility of Node.js. The cordova module will automatically be downloaded by the npm utility.

   On OS X and Linux: *`$ sudo npm install -g cordova`*

   On Windows: *`C:\>npm install -g cordova`*

**Source** : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**So simple change your npm registry**

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.eu
npm install -g phonegap
```

and another way to install last version

```
npm install -g phonegap@3.4
```

I guess it is not a issue with GIT